# Constructing a FileStream from a handle produced by CreateFile gives an empty stream

Tags: c#, file, winapi, stream

I'm attempting to write a simple program that would take a CSV consisting of two columns, and given a keyword from the first column, return the corresponding value from the second one. The problem is that I need the CSV to be in an alternate data stream to make the program as portable as possible (I want to make it so that when the user drops a CSV file on the executable, the CSV is overwritten). That is why I'm trying to use WinAPI's CreateFile function -- .NET doesn't support alternate data streams. Unfortunately, I'm failing miserably.

In the current state, the program is supposed to read a file named test.csv. I want to do CreateFile on it, convert the intPtr handle to a SafeFileHandle and then pass the SafeFileHandle to a FileStream constructor. The best I've been able to achieve is an empty stream though. It doesn't seem to me that the program is actually getting the right handle. When I try "CREATE_ALWAYS" or "CREATE_NEW" instead of "OPEN_ALWAYS", I'm getting an "Invalid Handle" error, no matter what I do with the rest of the parameters. With "OPEN_ALWAYS", when I check the value of "stream.Name", I'm getting "Unknown".

Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles;

namespace Searcher
{
    public partial class Searcher : Form
    {
        public static List<string> keywords;
        public static List<string> values;

        public Searcher()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            //byte[] path = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("C:\\Users\\as\\Documents\\test.csv");
            SafeFileHandle safeADSHandle = NativeMethods.CreateFileW("test.csv",
            NativeConstants.GENERIC_READ,
            NativeConstants.FILE_SHARE_READ,
            IntPtr.Zero,
            NativeConstants.OPEN_ALWAYS,
            0,
            IntPtr.Zero);
            //var safeADSHandle = new SafeFileHandle(handle, true);
            if (safeADSHandle.IsInvalid)
            {
                Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(Marshal.GetHRForLastWin32Error());
            }
            var stream = new FileStream(safeADSHandle, FileAccess.Read);
            MessageBox.Show(stream.Name);
            var reader = new StreamReader(stream);
            Searcher.keywords = new List<string>();
            Searcher.values = new List<string>();
            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                var line = reader.ReadLine();
                var values = line.Split(',');
                Searcher.keywords.Add(values[0]);
                Searcher.values.Add(values[1]);
            }
            cbKeyword.DataSource = Searcher.keywords;
            cbKeyword.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.ListItems;
        }

        private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            tbResult.Text = Searcher.values[cbKeyword.SelectedIndex];
        }
    }
}

public partial class NativeMethods
{
        [DllImportAttribute("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, EntryPoint = "CreateFile")]
        public static extern SafeFileHandle CreateFileW(
            [InAttribute()] [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string lpFileName,
            uint dwDesiredAccess,
            uint dwShareMode,
            [InAttribute()] System.IntPtr lpSecurityAttributes,
            uint dwCreationDisposition,
            uint dwFlagsAndAttributes,
            [InAttribute()] System.IntPtr hTemplateFile
        );
}


public partial class NativeConstants
{

        /// GENERIC_WRITE -> (0x40000000L)
        public const int GENERIC_WRITE = 1073741824;

        public const uint GENERIC_READ = 2147483648;

        /// FILE_SHARE_DELETE -> 0x00000004
        public const int FILE_SHARE_DELETE = 4;

        /// FILE_SHARE_WRITE -> 0x00000002
        public const int FILE_SHARE_WRITE = 2;

        /// FILE_SHARE_READ -> 0x00000001
        public const int FILE_SHARE_READ = 1;

        /// OPEN_ALWAYS -> 4
        public const int OPEN_ALWAYS = 4;
        public const int CREATE_NEW = 1;
}
```

Edit I've changed the code above slightly to reflect the changes after the comments. Now I'm not converting from IntPtr to SafeFileHandle. One thing to mention perhaps is that I before this change I tried reading the value of handle.ToString() to see if it was changing and it was -- it's a random number.

Comment: Instead of having a `IntPtr` and converting it to a `SafeFileHandle` you can just have your p/invoke call return the `SafeFileHandle` directly.

Comment: Also, Why are you using `CreateFile`? I don't notice you using anything that could not be done by just using a normal `FileStream`.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I'm testing on a regular file but the goal is to do it on an alternate data stream. Is it enough to change the return type of CreateFileW to get a SafeFileHandle? I'm sorry if it's obvious but this is deep water for me -- I've never tried to use WinAPI before.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain OK, I tried that and it complied but it's still showing "unknown" for stream.Name...

Comment: Is the handle that `CreateFile` returns valid? You should try setting the `SetLastError` field to true and check the return value of `GetLastWin32Error` to check if CreateFile is succeeding. More info [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.safehandles.safefilehandle(v=vs.110).aspx) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getlastwin32error%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: Hello @Sam, I modified the code and replaced it in my question. I've added the SetLastError field and the check for an invalid handle, but it's not throwing an exception and does the same thing as before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason this is not working is because you have specified an entry point without a character set. When you don't specify a character set in `DllImport`, the default is `CharSet.Ansi`, which means platform invoke will search for the function as follows:

- First for an unmangled exported function, i.e. the name `CreateFile` from the entry point that you specified (which does not exist in `kernel32.dll`)
- Next if the unmangled name was not found, it will search for the mangled name based on the charset, so it will search for `CreateFileA`

So it will find the `CreateFileA` exported function, which assumes any strings passed in to it are in 1-byte character ANSI format. However, you are marshalling the string as a wide string. Note that the wide-character version of the function is called `CreateFileW` (this distinction between ANSI and wide character versions of functions is common in the Windows API).

To fix this you just need to make sure that the marshalling of your parameters matches up with what the function you are importing expects. So you could remove the `EntryPoint` field, in which case it will use the C# method name to find the exported function instead (so it will find `CreateFileW`).

However to make it even clearer, I would write your platform invoke code as follows:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern IntPtr CreateFile(
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)] string filename,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] FileAccess access,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] FileShare share,
    IntPtr securityAttributes,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] FileMode creationDisposition,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] FileAttributes flagsAndAttributes,
    IntPtr templateFile);
```

I took this from the [pinvoke.net](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/CreateFile.html) website, which should be your go-to for writing pinvoke code rather than trying to bash it out yourself (especially if you aren't familiar with the Windows API or marshalling :).

The reason there was no error is probably because `CreateFile` was creating the file since it wouldn't have been able to find it.

The file name will appear as "[Unknown]" though. I suspect this is because the code to get a file name from a handle is non-trivial.

Comment: This worked!!! I'm definitely going to become familiar with these things; they're too cool, confusing and ugly not to take an interest in them :) Thank you very much. I was about to give up for today!

Comment: Good stuff! Definitely explore the pinvoke web site. There's also a tutorial on msdn [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468%28v=vs.71%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Comment: Since you are specifying a platform-dependent character set (`CharSet.Auto`), you should also set [ThrowOnUnmappableChar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute.throwonunmappablechar.aspx) to `true`. If you don't, you may silently ignore conversion errors. Besides that, [pinvoke.net](http://pinvoke.net/) is not a reliable source. It is commonly wrong.

Comment: What's a better source? I've usually found it to be okay, although I haven't written that much pinvoke code lately, and I often just write it myself anyway because I'm pretty familiar with the Win32 API. Also it's a wiki so it can be fixed if you see something wrong.